# Should My Class Translate to Core Data Managed Object, or Be Core Data Managed Object

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, ios6

I'm not sure which of these is the best practice, but it seems like a pretty common situation. I have a bunch of classes, so here's a simplified situation: I have a class called `Recorder` that records audio. It contains a bunch of settings for what volume to record at, what file to record at, etc.

I want to save it with core data.

1) Should I MAKE IT a Managed Object? Or should I write a separate Managed Object and add a method like `getManagedObject` and `initWithManagedObject` to `Recorder` in order to translate back and forth.

2) Or should I make `Recorder` a managed object.

Keep in mind that I subclass `Recorder` into `AudioRecorder`, so the core data model has to mirror that hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that both solutions are good.

If you only want to save your Recorder object to a persistent store (so that you can refetch it when your app is killed for instance) the first solution is great but you'll have two classes : Recorder and RecorderCoreData let's say.

If you think it's too complicated to maintain code with these two classes then convert your Recorder class to a managed object. The only thing you should be aware of is since AudioRecorder is a subclass of Recorder, AudioRecorder will also have to be a managed object !

But there's no perfect answer, just pick the one that looks easy and better depending on your needs.

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

### Use an `NSManagedObject` for your Recorder object.

There really is no down side to doing it this way. One design caveat you should be aware of, though, is that you generally should not add custom methods directly to the managed object class, otherwise it's easy to accidentally overwrite these changes when you update your managed object via the "Create NSManaged Subclass" in the data model editor. Instead, you can use class extensions.

If you find you need a lot of helper methods or custom properties -- neither of which is suited to class extensions -- *then* you should consider creating a proxy or manager object to interact with your recorder managed object.